# Laravel & Webpack plugins

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

Хочу использовать плагин webpack в laravel для обфускации JS (https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator), но не могу настроить сам webpack.

Из документации laravel ясно, что можно использовать метод `mix.webpackConfig({ ... })` в `webpack.mix.js`.

Мой пример: // webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const JavaScriptObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

mix.webpackConfig({
    entry: {
        'abc': '/public/js/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: '/public/js/',
        filename: '[name].js' // output: main.js
    },
    plugins: [
        new JavaScriptObfuscator ({
            rotateUnicodeArray: true
        }, ['abc.js']),
    ],
});
```

При запуске `npm run watch` выдаёт ошибку, `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'main.js'`

Воспользовался данным примером и webpack обфусцирует только app.js (resources/js/app.js):

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new JavaScriptObfuscator ({
            rotateUnicodeArray: true
        }, ['excluded_bundle_name.js']),
    ],
});
```

Как мне обфусцировать js файлы которые требуются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mix - это отдельная надстройка над webpack, которая перезаписывает entry и output, на значения указанные в:

```
mix.setPublicPath('path/to/public');
mix.setResourceRoot('prefix/for/resource/locators');
mix.js(src, output);
mix.react(src, output);
```

В вашем случае, скорее всего, лучше сделать отдельный конфиг для вебпака и настроить отдельную команду в package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "obfuscate": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js  --config=путь/к/вашему/конфигу.js"
    ...
  },
```

и отдельно запускать npm run obfuscate

Comment: Спасибо большое за направление - теперь всё работает как надо!